# How do I fix Chrome rendering of a simple navigation list?

Tags: html, css, encoding

I have a really odd problem that only happens in Chrome. I am using Chrome Version 37.0.2062.124 and OS X 10.9.5.

I have a simple menu that appears when I hover:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
  <li><a href="#">email@test.com</a>
     <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class=""><a href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Update card</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">Update Subscription</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#">View payment history</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Pretty standard procedure. The only problem is that it renders like this:

[image]

As you can see part of these li tags are not rendering. When I hover over the li tags themselves, however, they render properly. This only happens in Chrome and it does not happen in Chrome Canary.

Has anyone seen a problem like this before? If so I would be very grateful if you could help me fix it!

Comment: as you can see, the Update Subscription LI renders weird unlike the bottom ones. it seems the issue is in your chrome, try reinstalling it.

Comment: Need to see it 'not working'...can you reproduce in a JSfiddle example or a live link?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will work on getting an isolated example for you. Re: reinstalling Chrome - I tried this and I have the same issue on two Macs unfortunately.